# Create a rule in Prolog, cubeLess(X,B,R) which calculates the power of 3 and the remainder such that b =x3+r

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have this question in prolog. Q: Create a rule cubeLess(X,B,R) which calculates the power of 3 and the remainder such that b =x3+r. For an example cubeLess(2,10,R) should result in R=2. 
So far i have written the base case cubeLess(0,0,0)
AND
cubeLess(X,B,R) :- X>0,
                   X1 is X*X*X,
How do i go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume all numbers of relevance here are integers.
With SWI-Prolog, we can use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Next, we define predicate `cubeLess/3` like this:

```
cubeLess(X, B, R) :-
   B #= X^3 + R.
```

Sample query:

```
?- cubeLess(2, 10, R).
R = 2.
```

How about the most general query?

```
?- cubeLess(X, B, R).
X^3 #= _A,
_A+R #= B.
```

Not much propagation here... but that's OK!

If you are interested in ground solutions, constrain the finite domains and then use [`labeling/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=labeling/2).

Comment: I tried cubeLess(X,B,R):- B = X^3 + R. It did not work. Don't I have to write a rule to find R as well?  And is the recursion involve in this case?

Comment: There's a difference between `(=)/2` and `(#=)/2`. The "number-sign variant" is offered by clpfd.